# "ValueError: 1 is not a valid column name" error when using .save from openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a some code that opens an excel file that I created with another code.  It then does some basic formatting to the sheet and then saves and closes.  This code was working fine and then randomly I started getting some random errors on the .save function.  It says "Key Error '1'" and "1 is not a valid column name"

Below is my code

```
import openpyxl as opxl
from openpyxl.styles import Font, PatternFill

chime_low = 60
chime_high = 66
adj_low = -3
adj_high = 3
red_fill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFF0000', end_color='FFFF0000', fill_type='solid')
green_fill = PatternFill(start_color='0000FF00', end_color='0000FF00', fill_type='solid')

output_path = 'output.xlsx'
output = opxl.load_workbook(filename= output_path)
output_sheet = output.active
max_row = output_sheet.max_row
max_column = output_sheet.max_column

a1 = output_sheet['A1']
a1.font = Font(bold=True)
a1.value = 'Chime ID'

v_centerAlignment = opxl.styles.Alignment(
        horizontal="center", vertical="center", wrapText=True
    )

for col in output_sheet.iter_cols(min_row=1, min_col=1, max_row = max_row, max_col = max_column):
    for cell in col:
        cell_str = str(cell)
        col_let = cell_str[-3]
        cell.alignment = v_centerAlignment
        output_sheet.column_dimensions[f'{col_let}'].width = 20
      
        
for col in output_sheet.iter_cols(min_row=2, min_col=3, max_row = max_row, max_col = 3):
    for cell in col :
        if chime_low <= cell.value <= chime_high:
            cell.fill = green_fill
        else:
            cell.fill = red_fill
            
for col in output_sheet.iter_cols(min_row=2, min_col=4, max_row = max_row, max_col = 4):
    for cell in col :
        if adj_low <= cell.value <= adj_high:
            cell.fill = green_fill
        else:
            cell.fill = red_fill            
            
output.save(output_path)

output.close
```

And here is the current error

```
Formatting.py', wdir='C:/Users/LZMYKK/Documents/Python Scripts/Chime Automation')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File openpyxl\utils\cell.py:121 in openpyxl.utils.cell.column_index_from_string

KeyError: '1'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\lzmykk\documents\python scripts\chime automation\chime post processing excel formatting.py:49
    output.save(output_path)

  File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py:407 in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)

  File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py:293 in save_workbook
    writer.save()

  File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py:275 in save
    self.write_data()

  File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py:75 in write_data
    self._write_worksheets()

  File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py:215 in _write_worksheets
    self.write_worksheet(ws)

  File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py:200 in write_worksheet
    writer.write()

  File openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py:358 in openpyxl.worksheet._writer.WorksheetWriter.write

  File openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py:103 in openpyxl.worksheet._writer.WorksheetWriter.write_top

  File openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py:87 in openpyxl.worksheet._writer.WorksheetWriter.write_cols

  File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\dimensions.py:233 in to_tree
    for col in sorted(self.values(), key=sorter):

  File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\dimensions.py:227 in sorter
    value.reindex()

  File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\dimensions.py:176 in reindex
    self.min = self.max = column_index_from_string(self.index)

  File openpyxl\utils\cell.py:123 in openpyxl.utils.cell.column_index_from_string

ValueError: 1 is not a valid column name
```

I tried using a different filename for saving and it did not work.  I also got rid of the .save() line and the code runs but of course does not actually save any of my results.  Any help would be appreciated.  This code completely worked before.  I did make changes to the code that creates the output.xlsx file, but that file is all still in the same format and seems like it wouldn't cause this error.

If I run the code a second time after the first error I get a different error that says "File is not a zip file" and then if I run it again after this error, I get another different error that says "There is no item named '[Content_Types].xml' in the archive"

Comment: The `.save()` method of a workbook wants a filename as a parameter.  `output.save(output)` makes no sense, the workbook itself is not a filename.

Comment: Wow that was an oversight, I must have changed that.  Well I changed that line back to how it was supposed to be "output.save(output_path)" and I am back to getting the "ValueError: 1 is not a valid column name"

Comment: I have updated the question with the correct code and new error

Comment: Why try and use the string representation for a cell rather than one of its methods or properties?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have an issue with this bit of code which would cause a `"Key Error '1'" and "1 is not a valid column name"` error;

```
# for col in output_sheet.iter_cols(min_row=1, min_col=1, max_row=max_row, max_col=max_column):
for col in output_sheet.iter_cols(min_row=1, min_col=1, max_row=1, max_col=max_column):
    for cell in col:
        # cell_str = str(cell)
        # col_let = cell_str[-3]
        col_let = cell.column_letter
        cell.alignment = v_centerAlignment
        output_sheet.column_dimensions[f'{col_let}'].width = 20
```

You are determining column letter from `cell_str[-3]` which would work for cells in rows 1 to 9, like 'A1', 'A2', 'A3' returning 'A'. However when you reach row 'A10' and up [to 'A19'] the return is now 1 (until 'A20' where it will be 2 and so on). So then you have a column letter which is an integer and when you run this line

```
output_sheet.column_dimensions[f'{col_let}'].width = 20
```

you have a corrupted sheet. 
To get the column letter use

```
cell.column_letter
```

As CC points out; you dont need to loop thru all the used cells anyway, only the first row. The iteration should be `max_row=1`;

```
for col in output_sheet.iter_cols(min_row=1, min_col=1, max_row=1, max_col=max_column):
```

If this was done your error would never have occurred but your method to obtain the column letter should be changed either way.

See edits to your code sample above.

Also you do not need the line

```
output.close
```

for your code it does nothing.

Comment: You're still looping repeatedly through all the column dimensions.